# Why is there 2 APP Key in Laravel? .env and config/app.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I installed Laravel 5 via composer and after the installation the App Key was generated automatically. I went to `.env` file and I could see the APP_KEY there. However, I also noticed that there is another APP_KEY inside `config/app.php` like this:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

My newbie questions are:

1) Why is there App keys in 2 different locations?

2) When App Key was generated, why didnt it update the `config/app.php` file as well?

3) Do I need to manually paste the `.env` App key into the `config/app.php` file too or will that be not necessary as long as `.env` has it there?

4) During future updates, do I need to keep adding the App key into app.php file? Meaning, would it get reseted during updates?

Comment: config/app.php file is using your .env files key, see 'key' => env('app_key'), env() function is retrieving the key from .env file

Comment: aha..makes sense.. So do I just ignore the second argument `SomeRandomString` and leave it as it is?

Comment: yes, leave it as it is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value set in `config/app.php` is used if there is no value in the `.env` file. If you have set the app key in the `.env` file, the second argument in `app.php` is ignored.

Comment: that clears it. Thank you michael and @NehalHasnayeen